# FastAPI POST is insecure with docker and NPM

Tags: fastapi, nginx-reverse-proxy, uvicorn

I know there are many posts around this topic, however I'm facing an issue when using fastAPI in a docker container and Nginx Proxy Manager (NPM) is in front of it.

The application has many POSTs, however there is a particular one, when POSTing I get redirected to http and I get the following error from Edge:

> The information you’re about to submit is not secure Because this form
> is being submitted using a connection that’s not secure, your
> information will be visible to others.

My dockerfile CMD is:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--proxy-headers", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

The route and function is:

```
router = APIRouter(prefix="/records")
@router.post("/")
async def create_record(request: Request, user: dict = Depends(get_current_user),
                        name: str = Form(...), description: str = Form(...),
                        db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    record_model = Records()
    record_model.name = name
    record_model.description = description

    db.add(record_model)
    db.commit()

    return RedirectResponse(url="/records", status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
```

Here is the form:

```
 <form action="/records" method="POST">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your record name">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Your record description">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-link link-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            Cancel
          </a>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ms-auto" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
            Create new Record
          </button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Attached are the NPM screenshots:
[image]

[image]

As mentioned, what doesn't make sense is I can login (which is a POST) and I can do other POSTs for other functions.

The only thing I can think of is the fact that I'm using the form in a modal?

Comment: The login is on the same `fastAPI` server? I see the forward port as `8090` but you'r running `fastAPI` on port `80`. How are you running the container? Mapping 8090 to 80?

Comment: @Isabi Yes, the login is the same fastAPI server and yes, i'm mapping port 8090 to 80

Comment: In the first picture, I see that you declare `http` as scheme instead of `https`, but then force the `SSL`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I turned that on to force SSL redirection. The http scheme is because the container is port 80

Comment: Try using `https` instead. It is just a convention that http websites run on port 80. So, if you don't specify the port and the scheme is `http`, you get redirected to port 80. Instead, if scheme is `https`, you get redirected to port 443.

Comment: I'm surprised that https didn't kill the app all together, however the results were the same. I'm still kinda lost on how to navigate around this. Do you think it's worth ditching NPM and seeing if vanilla nginx handles it?

Comment: Nevermind, I accidentally was testing against the prod instance vs the lab. switching to https did fail and gives me a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Comment: that's a different error now. We're making some progress!. I suggest to open a new question with details of the error, if you think you need help. Also, closing this with the explanation of what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I figured it out. It only took me staying up till 3AM to solve it. Looking at the logs initially, seeing a 307 temporary redirect did not stand out. However, when sending a POST and you see a 307 redirect, then the problem is with the route or when you are posting the form.

In the question I have a

```
router = APIRouter(prefix="/records")
```

Then a route for the POST like this:

```
@router.post("/")
```

In the html form section I have

```
<form method="POST" action="/records">
```

Either the form should POST to `/records/` or the routes should not have the prefix and then a route of `@router.post("/")`

I have only tested removing the route prefix, but i'll most likely see if posting to `/records/` does the trick and makes life a little easier.